# Multiline assignment in bash

Tags: bash, sh

In .cmd files on windows I do:

```
SET JARS=^
./lib/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;^
./lib/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;^
./lib/bsh-1.3.0.jar;^
./lib/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;^
./lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar;^
./lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;^
./lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar;^
./lib/commons-io-2.0.1.jar;^
./lib/commons-io-2.3.jar;
```

How can I do such multiline assignment in shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question implicitly requests **single line output**, as I will show.

## test.bat

```
@SET JARS=^
./lib/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;^
./lib/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;^
./lib/bsh-1.3.0.jar;^
./lib/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;^
./lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar;^
./lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;^
./lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar;^
./lib/commons-io-2.0.1.jar;^
./lib/commons-io-2.3.jar;
@echo %JARS%
```

## Output

```
c:\home\Steven\Desktop>test.bat
./lib/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;./lib/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;./lib/bsh-1.3.0.jar;./li
b/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;./lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar;./lib/commons-collections-3.
2.1.jar;./lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar;./lib/commons-io-2.0.1.jar;./lib/commons-io-2
.3.jar;
```

## test.sh

```
JARS=\
'./lib/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;'\
'./lib/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;'\
'./lib/bsh-1.3.0.jar;'\
'./lib/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;'\
'./lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar;'\
'./lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;'\
'./lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar;'\
'./lib/commons-io-2.0.1.jar;'\
'./lib/commons-io-2.3.jar;'
echo "$JARS"
```

## Output

```
$ ./test.sh
./lib/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;./lib/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;./lib/bsh-1.3.0.jar;./li
b/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;./lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar;./lib/commons-collections-3.
2.1.jar;./lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar;./lib/commons-io-2.0.1.jar;./lib/commons-io-2
.3.jar;
```

Comment: @GordonDavisson, ah yes. Didn't pay attention to the semicolon. It should just need quotation on every element.

Answer (score 9):

So many ways to skin this cat.

```
JARS='
./lib/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;
./lib/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;
./lib/bsh-1.3.0.jar;
./lib/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;
./lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar;
./lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;
./lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar;
./lib/commons-io-2.0.1.jar;
./lib/commons-io-2.3.jar;
'
```

This gets you multiline input in a variable, per your question.

But if you're planning to USE these files in a shell script, you need to tell us how, so that we can come up with appropriate answers, rather than making us guess.  For use in a shell script, files need to be delimited by something useful.

You asked, "How can I do such multiline assignment in shell", but the assignment in your example is actually a SINGLE line, with the `^` at the end of each input line negating the following newline (*not* escaping it, as another answer suggested).

My solution in this answer is multiline, but you'll need to explain more about what you need this for in order to determine what will be useful.

For example, if you need to step through a list of files that will be processed with the `jar` command, you might want to have something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

JARS='
./lib/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
./lib/bsh-1.3.0.jar
...
'

set $JARS
for jarfile in "$@"; do
  jar xf "$jarfile" ...
done
```

Comment: If I say echo $JARS, then result string is space-separated.

Comment: Yes.  And if you say `echo "$JARS"`, you get the output formatted the way you specified it.  You should pay close attention to [how quotes are used in Bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).  They are extremely important.

Comment: Should I put new line character in the end of each string ?

Comment: @Fedir - if that's what you want, then sure.  If you want fine-grained control over what gets printed, use `printf` instead of `echo`.  If you have a use case that's different from the OP's, you might want to [pose it as its own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 6):

or alternatively

```
SOMEVAR=$( cat <<EOF
value1
value2
value3
value4
value5
EOF
)
```

Comment: This gives me: ./parser.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
./parser.sh: line 56: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Because the closing EOF can't be indented. **edit** you got it already. :)

Comment: it must have been a combination of markdown and whitespaces. Now corrected.